# Disable button onclick without using disable attribute

Tags: javascript

I have 3 buttons 'click me', 'disable', 'enable'. Basically when I click on 'click me' it triggers an alert but when I click on 'disable' it should disable the 'click me' button and change the button background colour and similarly, when i click 'enable it should enable 'click me' and change the background colour to original. It should be without using 'disabled' attribute

This GIF will give clear idea of what I want basically : https://gfycat.com/ickygloriousadouri

I tried using pointercancel but it didn't help.

```js
function disableButton() {
  var a = document.getElementById('clickme');
  a.addEventListener("pointercancel", function() {})
}

function enableButton() {
  var b = document.getElementById('clickme');
  b.addEventListener("pointerover", function() {
    b.style.backgroundColor = '#E2343F';
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
  <div class="">
    <button onclick="disableButton()" class="disable">Disable Button</button>
    <button onclick="enableButton()" class="enable">Enable Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And moreover if I can toggle the ID to change the css values.

It will be very helpful if someone can help me overcome this issue.

Comment: You don't want to **add** another event handler, you want to **remove** the existing one. See the documentation for [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

Comment: could just toggle [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/pointer-events) in css

Comment: I am very new to javascript. If you can help with the code

Comment: Why don't you try to add a class to the clickme button when he is disabled. In the event of this button you can then check if he is enabled or not and cancel the event instead of removing/adding it. The advantage (or disadvantage based on what you need) is that other events will not be concerned by this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is by adding and removing event listeners.

```js
const showAlert = () => alert('Hi');

const addListener = () => {
  const btn = document.querySelector('#clickme');
  clickListener = btn.addEventListener('click', showAlert);
  btn.classList.remove('disabled');
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  addListener();
  
});

function disableButton() {
  const btn = document.querySelector('#clickme'); 
  document.querySelector('#clickme').removeEventListener('click', showAlert);
  btn.classList.add('disabled');
}

function enableButton() {
  addListener();
}
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#clickme {
  background-color: #E2343F;
}

#clickme.disabled {
  cursor: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
  <div class="">
    <button onclick="disableButton()" class="disable">Disable Button</button>
    <button onclick="enableButton()" class="enable">Enable Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me to change the ID so that i can disable the cursor property and change the colour when disabled? @Bibberty

Comment: Sure. Let me tweak it

Comment: Yes Right. @TylerRoper

Comment: Thank you @Bibberty

Comment: Used some CSS to make the cursor more intuitive and also control colors, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bibberty. Works totally fine <3

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```css
.no-click {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Just add this class to your UI:

```html
<button class="no-click">
```

EDIT: If you want to toggle it instead of just disable it:

```
function disableButton() {
  var a = document.getElementById('clickme');
  a.css('pointer-events', 'none');
}

function enableButton() {
  var b = document.getElementById('clickme');
  a.css('pointer-events', '');
  b.addEventListener("pointerover", function() {
    b.style.backgroundColor = '#E2343F';
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
function disableButton() {
  document.getElementById('clickme').disabled = true;
}

function enableButton() {
  document.getElementById('clickme').disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
  <div class="">
    <button onclick="disableButton()" class="disable">Disable Button</button>
    <button onclick="enableButton()" class="enable">Enable Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```